# How to pad timestamp for LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to pad my sequence data for LSTM and my data x looks like

```
x = [[[1],[2],[3]],[[1],[2]],...]
```

and within the model, I try to pad like this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

x = Input(batch_shape = (None, None, 1), dtype = 'int32', name = 'x')
padded_x = pad_sequences(x, padding="post")
```

Then, I get an error saying:

```
len is not well defined for symbolic Tensors. (x:0) Please call `x.shape` rather than `len(x)` for shape information.
```

My guess is it happens because of `batch_shape = (None, None, 1)` in the input layer. But I need to use it as every sample has different timestamps.

Comment: If the input dimension is of variable length, you can use masking.
`x = keras.Input(shape=(None,None,1), dtype="int32")
masked_x = layers.Embedding(input_dim=5000, output_dim=16, mask_zero=True)(x) `